# How to enable async servlet support on Heroku?

Tags: java, servlets, heroku, asynchronous, servlet-3.0

When attempting to use async servlets on Heroku, I keep receiving this error message:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Async support must be enabled on a
>   servlet and for all filters involved in async request processing. This
>   is done in Java code using the Servlet API or by adding
>   "true" to servlet and filter
>   declarations in web.xml.

Confirmed that web.xml has `<async-supported>true</async-supported>` on every single servlet and filter.  I am also using New Relic for monitoring.  It is possible that Heroku and/or New Relic add their own servlets/filters which might be missing `<async-supported>true</async-supported>`? Any ideas on how to debug this?